# Harmonic Oscillation using Gaussian Quadrature

Tags: numerical-methods, physics, mathematical-physics

> Assume that the potential is symmetric with respect to zero and the system has amplitude $a$ suppose that the potential $V(x)=x^4$ and the mass of the particle is $m=1.$ Write a java function that calculates the period of the oscillator for given amplitude $a$ using Gaussian quadrature with $N=20$ points.

Relevant equations:
$$E_{\text{total energy}} = \frac12 m(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+V_{potential}(x)$$

and the period will be 
$$T_{period}=\sqrt{8m}\int^a_0\frac{dx}{\sqrt{V(a)-V(x)}},$$

but I don't have much experience with numerical methods so I am having difficulty proceeding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are asked:

> Assume that the potential is symmetric with respect to zero and the system has amplitude $a$ suppose that the potential $V(x)=x^4$ and the mass of the particle is $m=1.$ Write a java function that calculates the period of the oscillator for given amplitude $a$ using Gaussian quadrature with $N=20$ points.

We want to find the period using [*Gaussian Quadrature*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature) with $N=20$ points, $m = 1$, $a = a$: 
$$T_{period}=\sqrt{8m}\int^a_0\frac{dx}{\sqrt{V(a)-V(x)}} = \sqrt{8m}\int^a_0\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^4-x^4}}$$

First, refer to this [*website*](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/numerical-methods/numerical-integration/) for the Abscissae and Weights for the case $N = 20$ as those are needed for the calculation.

For [*Gaussian Quadrature*](https://math.okstate.edu/people/yqwang/teaching/math4513_fall14/Notes/gaussian.pdf) (see examples if this is not clear so you understand the algorithm), we have to make a change of variables since we are not integrating over $(-1, 1)$, so we have:

$$\displaystyle \int_r^s f(x)~dx = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \left(\dfrac{s-r}{2}\right) f\left(\dfrac{(s-r)x_i+(s+r)}{2}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \left( \dfrac a2 \right) f\left(\dfrac{a(x_i+1)}{2}\right)$$

So, for your particular problem, this reduces to:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \left( \dfrac a2 \right) f\left(\dfrac{a(x_i+1)}{2}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{20} c_i \left( \dfrac a2 \right) \dfrac{\sqrt{8}}{\sqrt{a^4-\left(\dfrac{a(x_i+1)}{2}\right)^4}}$$

where the $c_i$ are the weights and $x_i$ are the abscissae from the linked website ($N=20$).

This leads to the result:

$$\displaystyle \sqrt{8}\int^a_0\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^4-x^4}} = \frac{3.648094084043220866317961523913682543919262381332 }{a}$$

The exact result for this integral is given by:

$\displaystyle \sqrt{8}\int^a_0\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{a^4-x^4}} = \dfrac{2 \sqrt{2 \pi } \Gamma \left(\dfrac{5}{4}\right)}{a \Gamma \left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)}=\dfrac{3.7081493546027438368677006943905200924351976470435}{a}$

For example, if we compare the exact result to the Gaussian Quadrature result for $a = 5$, we get:

$$\mbox{Exact}~ = 0.74162987092054876737354013887810401848703952940871$$

versus

$$\mbox{Gaussian}~ = 0.729618816808644173263592304782736508783852476266$$

For the Java, you might look at [*Gaussian Quadrature Methods*](http://flylib.com/books/en/4.201.1.221/1/), but this is a problem that I cannot help you with since that code needs mods and I am not the person to talk to that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have to study this thoroughly and carefully to understand it.

Comment: There is some slight ambiguity as to whether Gauss-Legendre quadrature (that is, Gauss quadrature with a weight function which is constantly $1$) or some other Gauss-type quadrature is intended here. Because this integral is actually singular (there is a blowup at $x=a$), there is some reason to consider a method with a different weight function, such as Chebyshev-Gauss quadrature.

Comment: @Ian: That is a good point, but I followed the instructions as given. I assumed that that was what was intended by the OP or whomever assigned this problem. In fact, I did not really understand why they chose $N = 20$, what was the rationale for that choice too. Hopefully, he can use this as a model if he wants to change the method as it seems like this is a programming assignment. If he does need that, he can look at: http://ice.uchicago.edu/2012_presentations/Faculty/Judd/Quadrature_ICE11.pdf

Comment: Oh yes, your post is fine. That was more for the benefit of @Luffy .

Comment: @Ian I don't think I understand your comment? So there are other types of Gauss quadrature?

Comment: @Luffy There is a Gauss quadrature-type method for calculating integrals of the form $\int f(x) w(x) dx$, provided that $w \geq 0$ and for any polynomial $p$, $p(x) w(x)$ is integrable on the interval in question. "Standard" Gauss quadrature can also be called Gauss-Legendre quadrature and uses $w(x)=1$.

Comment: @Luffy Here are a few more examples. Chebyshev-Gauss quadrature uses $w(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ on $[-1,1]$, which is often useful for dealing with functions with integrable singularities at one or both endpoints of a finite interval (like yours). Gauss-Hermite quadrature uses $w(x)=\exp(-x^2)$ on the entire line. I have forgotten the name, but there is another type which uses $w(x)=\exp(-x)$ on the right half of the line.

Comment: @Amzoti I have a question, for the $x_i$ and $c_i$ how are they applied? I looked at the links you provided but I am still confused. So if we start at $x_1,c_1$ then we use $x_1 =+0.0765$ and $c_1 = 0.1527$ and substitute it into our summation and then for $i=2$ do we use $x_2= -0.0765$ and $c_2 = 0.1527$ and then add the results of $i=2$ and $i=1$?

Comment: @Luffy: That is correct, but if I were you, I would look at the simple examples in the linked paper and then compare those to the website and then to my answer (work that simpler example and make sure you get the result and then work the one with the 20 points). It will really save you a lot of grief! This one: https://math.okstate.edu/people/yqwang/teaching/math4513_fall14/Notes/gaussian.pdf

Comment: @Amzoti Thank you! My last question, for the weights and abscissas is there a general formula for finding them?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature